# How do i get hidden value from Kendo grid with onSave event

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, events, grid, kendo-ui

i have a edit button and in Kendo grid onSave event that will fire up when i change something in a row. Now i want to access dataItem values when i update row but for some reason it's always null, what am i doing wrong? I have no problems accessing value in drop down menu tho but i also need hidden values.

**JS**

```
function onSave(e) {
        if (e.model.StatusIdD) {     
            e.model.StatusIdD = 0;
            var currentlySelectedValue = $(e.container).find('#StatusIdD').data("kendoDropDownList").value();
            var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.target).closest("tr"));
            var bojaTeksta = dataItem.BojaTeksta;
            console.log(bojaTeksta);
            e.model.set('StatusIdD', currentlySelectedValue);
            e.model.set('Status', $(e.container).find('#StatusIdD').data("kendoDropDownList").text());
            //e.model.set('BojaPozadine', currentlySelectedValue);
            //e.model.set('BojaTeksta', currentlySelectedValue);
        }     
    }
```

Grid - simplified

```
...
columns.Bound(p => p.BojaTeksta).Hidden(true);
columns.Bound(p => p.BojaPozadine).Hidden(true);
...
.Events(e => e.Remove("onRemove").Save("onSave"))
```

ANSWER

i managed to get data with selectedItem rather then dataItem (when you click a command button you automatically select a row)

```
var grid = $("#Grid" + '@guid').data("kendoGrid"); 
var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select()); 
var bojaTeksta = selectedItem.BojaTeksta; 
var bojaPozadine = selectedItem.BojaPozadine; 
console.log(bojaTeksta); 
console.log(bojaPozadine);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have any trouble getting hold of a hidden value.

First make sure the BojaTeksta is set. By inspecting the generated html.

It should look something like:

```
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none">123</td>
```

Check to see if you are getting other values from your dataItem. Values that are not hidden.

If not try using the currentTarget instead of target on the event:

```
var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
```

Comment: Hi, i am still getting a null value when i use var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr")); (in my onSave function i used var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.target).closest("tr"));) Any input?

Comment: I also tried to make on edit event but for some reason it wont get dataItems. Only time when i successfully used dataItem is with custom command button, but i'm not sure how do i call in grid edit with custom button

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ example? According to the documentation here: http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#methods-dataItem your code should work.

Comment: i managed to get data with selectedItem rather then dataItem (when you click a command button you automatically select a row)

var grid = $("#Grid" + '@guid').data("kendoGrid");
var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
var bojaTeksta = selectedItem.BojaTeksta;
var bojaPozadine = selectedItem.BojaPozadine;
console.log(bojaTeksta);
console.log(bojaPozadine);

Thank you for your help ;)